# If f satisfies $({\partial^2f\over \partial x^2}+{\partial ^2f\over\partial y^2})f(x,y)>0$, for every $(x,y)∈ R^2$ show that f has no local maximum.

Tags: calculus, multivariable-calculus

If f satisfies $$({\partial^2f\over \partial x^2}+{\partial ^2f\over\partial y^2})f(x,y)>0$$, for every $(x,y)∈ R^2$ show that f has no local maximum.

Comment: Can you move the information from the title to the description? There's no reference to U in the question. Looks like the greater than, less than signs are being used inconsistently.

Comment: Also, please put the question in the body as well.

Comment: @TurlocTheRed U is a subset of $R^2$ is not specified .Thank you for pointing it out.What is wrong with the signs?

Comment: Are you sure the question didn't say $ \left( \frac{\partial^2}{\partial x^2} + \frac{\partial^2}{\partial y^2} \right) f(x,y) > 0$ ?

Comment: Then that's the same as $\dfrac{\partial^2 f}{\partial x^2} + \dfrac{\partial^2 f}{\partial y^2}$.

Answer (score 1):

You are correct that the question as stated is wrong (You probably just read it incorrectly). It’s not sufficient to just point out that the sum of second derivatives is negative since one might be positive and the other negative.

You can however just construct a counterexample. $-1-x^2-y^2$ is an example function with its product being $(-4)(-1-x^2-y^2)>0$ and a maximum at $(0,0)$.

Comment: Thank you for providing a counterexample.My thinking process was if ${\partial f \over \partial x}= {\partial f \over \partial y}=0$ ,${\partial^2f\over \partial x^2}<0$ and the hessian is positive ${\partial^2f\over \partial x^2} {\partial^2f\over \partial y^2}> ({\partial^2f\over \partial x\partial y})^2$.Then f has a local maximum and ${\partial^2f\over \partial y^2}<0$ .Both of partial derivatives are negative and $({\partial^2f\over \partial x^2}+ {\partial^2f\over \partial y^2})f(x,y)>0$ holds if $f(x,y)<0$.Therefore,again we have a contradiction.Yet,my thinking process may be incorrect.

Comment: Err, no. $-e^x-e^y$ also satisfies the condition but has no local maximum, so it’s not false for every $f$ so it’s impossible to derive a contradiction for a general $f$.

Answer (score 0):

You’re missing one extra condition about the sign of $f$; besides that, there’s nothing special about 2-dimensions. Here’s the general theorem

> **Theorem.**
>
> Let $\Omega\subset\Bbb{R}^n$ be a connected open set and suppose $f:\Omega\to\Bbb{R}$ is a $C^2$ function such that $(\Delta f)f>0$ on $\Omega$. Then, either $f$ has no local maximum on $\Omega$ or $-f$ has no local maximum on $\Omega$.

- **Proof #1:** Note that our hypothesis $(\Delta f)f>0$ implies that $f$ is nowhere vanishing on $\Omega$. By connectedness of $\Omega$, it follows the image $f(\Omega)$ is connected (hence an interval) and hence $f$ maintains a constant sign. Note that our hypothesis of $(\Delta f)f>0$ is unchanged by switching $f$ with $-f$. Therefore, we may without loss of generality suppose $f>0$ on $\Omega$. This implies that $\Delta f>0$ on $\Omega$, meaning $f$ is [subharmonic](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Subharmonic_function#Properties)*. The maximum principle for subharmonic functions implies that if $f$ has a local maximum, then it is constant in some neighborhood $\Omega_0$ of that point, but this means the first and hence second derivatives vanish identically on $\Omega_0$ which violates the inequality $\Delta f>0$. Therefore, $f$ has no local maximum points.
- **Proof #2:** As above, we may without loss of generality suppose $f>0$ and hence by dividing, $\Delta f>0$ on $\Omega$. Suppose now that $f$ has a local maximum at some point $p$. Then, Taylor’s theorem implies that the Hessian matrix $Hf(p)$ is negative-semidefinite (this is the analogue of the fact that in 1-dimension, for a twice differentiable function $\phi$, if $x_0$ is a local maximum, then $\phi’(x_0)=0$ and $\phi’’(x_0)\leq 0$). Thus, all the eigenvalues, $\lambda_1,\dots,\lambda_n$ of $Hf(p)$ are $\leq 0$ (the eigenvalues exist in $\Bbb{R}$ since the Hessian is a real, symmetric matrix), so
  \begin{align}
  \Delta f(p)=\text{trace}(Hf(p))=\sum_{i=1}^{n}\lambda_i\leq 0,
  \end{align}
  which is a contradiction. Thus, $f$ has no local maximum.

---

<sub>* A side remark about terminology: the condition $\Delta f\geq 0$ is known as *subharmonic*, which may sound counterintuitive. Well, the reason for the existing terminology is that it is the operator $-\Delta$ which decides the naming conventions, because this is a *positive operator* (more precisely non-negative) in the sense that for all smooth compactly supported functions $\phi$, $\int_{\Bbb{R}^n}(-\Delta \phi)\phi\,dx=\int_{\Bbb{R}^n}\|\nabla\phi\|^2\,dx\geq 0$. So, a function $f$ is said to be subharmonic, or superharmonic or harmonic according to whether $-\Delta f\leq 0$ or $-\Delta f\geq 0$ or $-\Delta f=0$.</sub>